# How to reset static variables when activity is over?

Tags: java, android, variables, static

I want to reset static int variable on Android, when the Activity finalize.

Without using:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   var = 0;
   finish();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just initialize them in onCreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset them in the activity's `onDestroy()` method which is called at the end of the activity lifecycle. Or just initialize them in `onCreate()` as Mr. Trigg said.